# Ionic-React multiple selection losing previously selected values

Tags: reactjs, ionic5

I am quite new to app-programming so apologies if my questions is too basic.

Form the multiple selection feature in ionic-react, I am able to extract the values selected by the user. But when the user goes back to to select more values, the previously selected values disappear.

How can I have the previous selections in place?

I provide an example from Ionic documentation.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { IonContent, IonItem, IonLabel, IonList, IonListHeader, IonSelect, IonSelectOption, IonPage, IonItemDivider } from '@ionic/react';

const users = [
  {
    id: 1,
    first: 'Alice',
    last: 'Smith'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    first: 'Bob',
    last: 'Davis'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    first: 'Charlie',
    last: 'Rosenburg',
  }
];

type User = typeof users[number];

const compareWith = (o1: User, o2: User) => {
  return o1 && o2 ? o1.id === o2.id : o1 === o2;
};

export const ObjectSelection: React.FC = () => {

  const [selectedUsers, setSelectedUsers] = useState<User[]>([]);

  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonContent>
        <IonList>
          <IonListHeader>
            <IonLabel>
              Objects as Values (compareWith)
            </IonLabel>
          </IonListHeader>
          <IonItem>
            <IonLabel>Users</IonLabel>
            <IonSelect compareWith={compareWith} value={selectedUsers} multiple onIonChange={e => setSelectedUsers(e.detail.value)}>
              {users.map(user => (
                <IonSelectOption key={user.id} value={user}>
                  {user.first} {user.last}
                </IonSelectOption>
              ))}
            </IonSelect>
          </IonItem>
          <IonItemDivider>Selected Users</IonItemDivider>
          {selectedUsers.length ?
            selectedUsers.map(user => <IonItem key={user.id}>{user.first} {user.last}</IonItem>) :
            <IonItem>(none selected)</IonItem>
          }
        </IonList>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are updated the state directly using `onIonChange={e => setSelectedUsers(e.detail.value)}` which will directly change the value of `selectedUsers`. You first need to fetch the value of selectedUsers and then append the new values in it.

```
onIonChange={e => setSelectedUsers([...selectedUsers, e.detail.value])}
```

Comment: Hey. I tried your solution, but it goes into an infinite loop (or the browser stops responding).

Comment: Can u just console n show me what are the values present for `e.detail.value` and `selectedUsers`. I'm unable to understand the structure.